# file_get_contents api link two connections with session

Tags: php, api, session, file-get-contents

I have two api pages, api1.php and api2.php. On 1 there is set an session and on 2 this session needs to be returned. 
Ofcourse there will be additional functions but my goal of this is to link those two api connections to one and eachother by using a session.

api1.php:

```
session_start();

$api_key = 'dfdsakdsfjdskfjdskfdsjfdfewfifjjsd';

$_SESSION['api_key'] = $api_key;
setcookie('api_key', $api_key);
```

api2.php:

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['api_key'];
echo $_COOKIE['api_key'];
```

test.php:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/api1.php';
$content1 = file_get_contents($url);

$url2 = 'http://example.com/api2.php'; 
$content2 = file_get_contents($url2);
echo $content2;
```

As you may have noticed, i'm visiting the page test.php to obtain a result.
But no result is being returned.
Can somebody tell me why this is not working and what may be an additional way of making all of this happen?

(Notice: the example.com are both the same site (mine))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code "links" correctly.  The problem is actually in test.php!  Instead of executing the code contained in both files, it retrieves the entire file.  If you view source you will note the PHP tags and your code. A better solution to check if this is working is to go to api1.php and api2.php separately.  With some code adjustments you could also just use the include() or require() functions.  Which would look like this:

api2.php

```
echo $_SESSION['api_key'] . "\n<br/>\n";
echo $_COOKIE['api_key'];
```

test.php

```
include('api1.php');
include('api2.php');
```

It's worth noting the using the include and require functions executes the code in api1.php and api2.php as if that code were a part of test.php.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem however is that include and require Will only solve the issue on a local host. The api files however are located elsewhere in order to make the api work from any website.